# "Delete" vs. "Remove"

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm implementing a method in my container class that removes/deletes one value from the array.  For example:

```
// | 532 | 422 | 134 | 762 |
// |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |

MyObject.Remove(1); // Or MyObject.Delete(1);

// | 532 | 134 | 762 |
// |  0  |  1  |  2  |
```

Which word is more commonly-used for this type of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library containers use "erase". "Delete" might be confused with deleting a memory allocation. The standard library algorithms with "remove" in the name don't actually change the size of the container (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Comment: +1 if you use the same word as the standard library everyone will know what it does.